# WPF C# wrong mouse coordinates

Tags: c#, wpf, opencv, emgucv

So im trying to get mouse coordinates from a click on an image, and it gives the wrong coordinates. When i move the mouse to draw, the line appears away from the cursor.
This is the code i use to get the mouse coordinates:

```
    private void ponaredek_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        mouseDown = true;
        //x1 = System.Windows.Forms.Control.MousePosition;
        x1 = new System.Drawing.Point((int)e.GetPosition(this).X, (int)e.GetPosition(this).Y);
    }
```

x1 is of type System.Drawing.Point (i need the point from drawing, to use in emgucv). What do i have to do to correct the cursor location (i drew where the cursor was)
[image]

Comment: What type of element is the `MouseDown` event being captured on? Understanding your XAML would help here.

Comment: Is your screen scaled?

Comment: @Jeff yes,
 WindowState="Maximized" ResizeMode="NoResize" Height="1080" Width="1920"
i have the height and width set just so i can edit better

Comment: @Keithernet its on an image element

Comment: I am not sure that my question is clear.  Have you set a scale factor for your monitor in the Settings > Display > Scale and layout?

Comment: @Jeff no, i have not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to get the mouse position relative to the Image element, not the Window. So replace

```
e.GetPosition(this)
```

by

```
e.GetPosition((IInputElement)sender)
```

or

```
e.GetPosition(ponaredek)
```

if that is the Image element.

It should look like this:

```
var pos = e.GetPosition((IInputElement)sender);
x1 = new System.Drawing.Point(pos.X, pos.Y);
```

Also make sure the Image element's `Stretch` property is set to `None`.

Comment: it is still not in the correct position, but a bit closer to the cursor

Comment: Also make sure the Image element's Stretch property is set to None. If the Image is stretched, you would have to take the stretch ratios into account.